# Keep unique activities around after swiping one activity off recent app list

Tags: android, android-activity

I have two activities in an application I am creating.  I have both activities set up to use their own process.  The two activities use the `singleTask` `android:launchMode`, a unique `android:process` value, and a unique `android:taskAffinity` value.

When I have both activities running, they both show in the recent apps list, and are using unique processes.

When I swipe either activity, it also kills the process of the other activity.

Is there a way to prevent this action?  I want the swipe to remove ONLY the activity I was actually swiping.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use Fragments then?

Comment: The business logic requires complete separate instances of the application in order to correctly function.  An example of what I need: a user starts my application.  A list of images are displayed.  At this point if the user taps on a .png file, a .png editor activity opens.  If the user taps on a .jpg file, a .jpg editor activity opens.  Sorry - as close to an explanation I can think of.

As far as I understand (and I'm still quite new at this), using fragments would help me get two UI "portions".  The fragments would still be tied to an activity at some point, so the same issue would exist!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that this is the correct behavior, although undefined officially.

Swiping any activity off of the recent apps list will also close any other activities open that are associated with the application.  Services will be kept running, but are notified that the associated activities have been closed.